# HTTP Status 400: The requested resource is not available

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, spring-boot

Can you help me on this one please, I am encountering *HTTP Status 400: The requested resource is not available* everytime I click my button EDIT and DELETE and I can't fix this for weeks now, could someone advice me on this please? Below are my codes:

**USER CONTROLLER**

```js
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/ims-user")
public class IMSUserController {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IMSUserController.class);
 private static final String SAVE_ACTION = "/ims-user/save";
 private static final String UPDATE_ACTION = "/ims-user/update";

 @Autowired
 private IMSUserService imsUserService;

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String loadIMSUserList(Model model) {
  logger.info("Getting all IMS Users");
  model.addAttribute("imsUserList", imsUserService.getAllIMSUsers());
  return "imsUserList";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String loadIMSUserForm(Model model) {
  logger.info("Creating new IMS User");
  IMSUser imsUser = new IMSUser();
  model.addAttribute("imsUser", imsUser);
  model.addAttribute("action", SAVE_ACTION);
  buildModel(model, imsUser, SAVE_ACTION);
  return "imsNewUserForm";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/view/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String loadIMSUserForm(Model model, @PathVariable Long id) {
  logger.info("Viewing User");
  IMSUser imsUser = imsUserService.getIMSUserById(id);
  model.addAttribute("imsUser", imsUser);
  return "imsViewUserForm";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String saveIMSUser(@Validated @ModelAttribute("imsUser") IMSUser imsUser, BindingResult result, Model model,
   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  imsUserService.addIMSUser(imsUser);
  return "redirect:/ims-user";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String deleteIMSUser(@PathVariable Long id) {  
  logger.info("Deleting User");  
  IMSUser imsUser = imsUserService.getIMSUserById(id);  
  imsUserService.deleteIMSUser(imsUser);
  return "redirect:/ims-user";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String editIMSUser(@PathVariable Long id, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  
 logger.info("Loading edit for of IMSUser with the following details");
  IMSUser imsUser = imsUserService.getIMSUserById(id);
  

  if (imsUser == null) {
   return "redirect:/ims-user";
  }
  buildModel(model, imsUser, UPDATE_ACTION);

  return "imsEditUser";
```

**VIEW-USER.JSP**

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" /> ">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="<c:url value="/resources/css/utility.css" /> ">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" /> ">

</head>

<form:form modelAttribute="imsUser" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/delete" method="GET" >
 <form:hidden path="id"/>
 <input type="button" id="btn-user-edit" value="Edit" class="btnHeader button" onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit/{imsUser.id}'"/>
</form:form>


<body>

  <div class="form-user">
   <ul>
    <c:out value="${action}"/>
    
    <li><label><strong> User Type     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value="Employee"/></span></li> 
    
    <li><label><strong> Username     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.username}" /></span></li>
    
    <li><label><strong> Password     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.password}" /></span></li>
    
    <li><label><strong> Client Name     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value="Biolinks"/></span></li>
    
    <li><label><strong> First Name     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value="${imsUser.firstname}" /></span></li>
    
    <li><label><strong> Middle Name     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.middlename}" /></span></li>
    
    <li><label><strong> Last Name     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.lastname}" /></span></li> 
      
    
    <li><label><strong> Contact Number     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.contactNumber}" /></span></li>
    
    <li><label><strong> E-mail Address     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.emailAddress}" /></span></li>
    
    <li><label><strong> Address     : </strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.address}"/></span></li>  
       
    <li><label><strong> City     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.city}"/></span></li>
    
    <li><label><strong> Postal Code     :</strong></label><span>
    <c:out value= "${imsUser.postalCode}" /></span></li>
    
   </ul>
  
 
  </div>

</body>
</html>

<div id="deleteUserDialog" title="Please Confirm" class="hidden">
  Are you sure you want to delete this user?
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function deleteUser()
{

  document.getElementById("imsUser").submit();
  
} 



</script>
```

**EDIT-USER.JSP**

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>


<form:form id="imsUser" modelAttribute="imsUser" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}${action}" method="GET" cssClass="form-user">
  <form:hidden path="id"/>
  <c:out value="${imsUser.id}"/>
  
  <ul>
     
    <li><label><strong> Username </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="username" /></li>
    <li><label><strong> Password </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="password" /></li>
    <li><label><strong> First Name </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="firstname" /></li>
    <li><label><strong> Middle Name </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="middlename" /></li>
    <li><label><strong> Last Name </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="lastname" /></li>
    <li><label><strong> Contact Number </strong></label>:<form:input
     type="text" path="contactNumber"/></li>   
    <li><label><strong> E-mail Address </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="emailAddress" /></li>
    <li><label><strong> Address </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="address" /></li>
    <li><label><strong> City </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="city" /></li>
    <li><label><strong> Postal Code </strong></label>:<form:input
      type="text" path="postalCode" /></li>
  
   
  </ul>
</form:form>
```

Appreciate your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think your form is doing POST request and not DELETE/PUT. You can look at browser's dev console to confirm it.

You can pass action=delete/put as request parameter from your form. And add HiddenHttpMethodFilter to your spring application.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more mapping on the class level in your controller which is `@RequestMapping(value = "/ims-user")`

The button should be submitted with  :

*`onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ims-user/edit/{imsUser.id}'"`*

and not

*`onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit/{imsUser.id}'"`*

Answer (score 0):

I have a look in your code and i would try to change a little things first.

your view page have the form out of body section, I think that put it into body section can help a little.

The button delete, I think that you can change it for a link (<a href ...) to your route and with this, you don't need a form and etc. In this case, you can format you link to it look like a button, for example, using bootstrap, class="btn btn-default", more examples in getboostrap.com.

I write a example project a time ago. In this project you will see some examples and I hope this help you.

https://bitbucket.org/macielbombonato/apolo

Sorry for my bad english and if you need some help, fell free to contact me.

Editing to add some code...

In view jsp

```
</head>
<body>

<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ims-user/edit/{imsUser.id}" class="btn btn-default">
Edit
</a>

...
```

Your Delete button can use the same style, but you need to change your controller to this work. Normally I use a link like this in my controller:

```
/ims-user/entity/1
```

And use the method delete

Look this class in that example:
[UserAPIController](https://bitbucket.org/macielbombonato/apolo/src/308eccdbca3c6cb9d792c67c25375130b26ec1cb/apolo-web-core/src/main/java/apolo/web/controller/UserAPIController.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

With this your URL will be

```
/ism-user/1
```

But in your case you can simple include de id in the method call

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ims-user/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteIMSUser(@PathVariable Long id)
```

With this, your delete button will be something like this:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ims-user/delete/{imsUser.id}" class="btn btn-default">
Delete
</a>
```

Don't forget, your tags need to stay in right location, so, you need to put forms, buttons and others thins inside of body.

I hope I've helped you.

Comment: Hi, i've tried to look on the link that you have shared to me but then its not in english so I couldn't understand that well.  I made some changes as per your advise but now i am getting different error stating "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect".     Sorry I am a newbie to java programming and no proper training on this one :(

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer to try to explain better. If you have problems yet, contact me.